# Product import from Volusion to Magento Store

Tags: magento, csv, product

We have a Store that is in Volusion, It has about 500 Products, Now we want to Get our store in Magento, We have already finished our store in Magento, So i need suggestions. how can I add all product from volusion to Magento quickly and easily.
thanks

Comment: Have you already tried CSV imports? We can't help without knowing what you've tried and knowing what didn't work, and which errors you may be getting.

Comment: I can import product by CSV in magento. But but i don't know how can i export product from volusion. so i need a solution so that i can export all product from volusion and import it in magento directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say hello to your new best friend:

- [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpwebsite/magmi/) (free)
- [uRapidFlow](http://www.unirgy.com//products/urapidflow/) (paid)

You only need 1 of them, I've never used uRapidFlow (I'm about to, though) but heard good things about him, and used Magmi plenty with full satisfaction.
HTH

Comment: thanks for response. may be these two are for CSV import for magento. But I need to import volusion product to magento. is it possible ? thanks

Comment: @ShamimAhmed you need to export the products from volusion in a csv file, respecting the structure Magento and those importer understand and then import them. So, yes, it's possible.